# Новый опрос при обновлении страницы

Tags: javascript

Можно ли написать скрипт, чтобы при обновлении страницы появлялся другой код, например,
такой:

```
<div id="vk_poll1"></div> <script type="text/javascript"> VK.Widgets.Poll("vk_poll1", {width: "200"}, "11578523_5ed71790f94fe22de7"); </script>
```

А при обновлении страницы:

```
<div id="vk_poll"></div> <script type="text/javascript"> VK.Widgets.Poll("vk_poll", {width: "200"}, "13362052_b154dc799a25937507"); </script>
```

Comment: @doove, Если вы получили стоящий ответ, отметьте его как принятый.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Конечно можно.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    polls=['"11578523_5ed71790f94fe22de7"','"13362052_b154dc799a25937507"'];
    poll_num=Math.floor(Math.random()*polls.length);
    VK.Widgets.Poll("vk_poll", {width:"200"},polls[poll_num]);
    </script>
```

Comment: мб я чтото не допонял, но неработает :(

Comment: Отображается, но пишет Wrong poll_id

Comment: попробуйте из массива убрать двойные кавычки.

Comment: Дааааааааа! Огромное спасибо!

Comment: Для спасибо есть кнопка